# scrollBy() doesn't scroll

Tags: android, view, scroll

I'm trying to create a custom view with the height bigger than the display's (or parent's) height. This view must be scrollable. I use onTouchEvent to measure new finger position, and I actually get what I want, but my view doesn't move. I've searched in the internet for the problem's solution, but didn't find a suitable answer. 
This's my View

```
public class SmartScroll extends View{
public SmartScroll(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

int count = 0;
int yStart = 0, yEnd = 0;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            yStart = (int) event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            MeasureSpec.toString(getMeasuredHeight());
            MeasureSpec.toString(getMeasuredWidth());
            count++;
            yEnd = (int) event.getY();
            scrollBy(0, (yEnd - yStart));
            yStart = yEnd;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            yStart = 0;
            yEnd = 0;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this's how I create it inActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SmartScroll scrollView = new SmartScroll(getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1500, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        }
    };
    scrollView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient));
    setContentView(scrollView);
}
```

}

Please, help me to make it work

Comment: Instead of implementing a scrollable view why not simply wrap the custom view in a ScrollView/HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: This view is going to be a part of a big project with a quite complicated view hierarchy. Ar present time this functionality works as you suggested, but this custom view is needed for better managing of views' measuring and layouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find the answer on my question. I tried some working examples from the internet which use `scrollBy()` or `scrollTo()` and they really work.
So, I found  solution that works for me. As I couldn't move the content of my custom view, I decided to move the whole view.
I do this by listening to `onTouchEvents`, and setting new Y coordinates of my view. After setting new Y I call `invalidate()`.

**UPDATE:**

I finally found the reason of my initial problem. It was in the way I created my custom `ViewGroup`. I set height of my `ViewGroup` bigger than the height of its parent and wanted to scroll its content. But content was the same size of the very `ViewGroup`, so `scrollBy()` didn't find the need to scroll content.
What I did was I filled my `ViewGroup` with children so that the content became bigger than the view, measured my `ViewGroup` to `MatchParent` and `scrollBy()` finally started working.